# Well-posedness of BVP for Poisson's equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the BVP,
\begin{eqnarray}
-\Delta u&=&f \quad \text{ in } \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d,\\
u&=&g \quad \text{ on } \partial\Omega.
\end{eqnarray}
The well-known weak formulation of the above BVP is to look for  $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying

\begin{eqnarray}
-\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} \sum\limits_{i=1}^du_{x_i}v_{x_i} dx = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} fv dx \quad \text{ for all } v \in H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^d). \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
\end{eqnarray}

Why don't we consider the a more weaker (but more intuitive) definition: $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and satisfies the following weak formulation
\begin{eqnarray}
-\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}u \Delta\phi dx =\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} f\phi dx\quad \text{ for all } \phi\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^d). \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad(2)
\end{eqnarray}

Is it because of non uniqueness? If so, can wee explicitly construct two different $L^2$ functions satisfying the weak formulation(2)?

P.S.: Clearly weak solution in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying (1) will automatically satisfy (2). So existence is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require $u=g$ on $\partial\Omega$ as you stated. But if $u$ is just in $L^2$, then $u$ is not well-defined on $\partial\Omega$. This is because you can change the value of an $L^2$ function on a zero measure set however you like and it'll still remain the same function. $\partial\Omega$ has 1 dimension less than $\Omega$, and so it's a zero measure set. On the other hand, if $u\in H^1$, then all is fine because you have the "trace theorem" which proved that $u$ will be well-defined on $\partial\Omega$, in the sense of a function in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$. The trace function in the theroem is a map $H^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ which shows that every $H^1$ function has a well-defined boundary.